# I am getting an error php. Undefined index

Tags: php

```
foreach($formattedDatas as $key => $formattedData) {    
        foreach ($formattedData as $keyFormat => $valueFormat) {        
                $brandDataArray['sales_price']  += $valueFormat['total_price'];
        }           
}
```

I am getting this notice:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: sales_price
Filename: models/sales_aggregated.php
Line Number: 34
```

Can somebody help me resolve this?

Comment: The array `$brandDataArray` does not have an index defined as `sales_price`

Comment: I think it is clear what is wrong.

Comment: initialize array first $brandDataArray = array();

Comment: Just inialize $brandDataArray['sales_price'] = 0; because $brandDataArray['sales_price'] += $valueFormat['total_price']; statement expects $brandDataArray['sales_price'] to exists and just increment the value on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `$brandDataArray['sales_price']` before you attempt to add to it.

```
// Assuming the array $brandDataArray already exists. 
// If not, initialize that too!
$brandDataArray['sales_price'] = 0;

// Then proceed...
foreach($formattedDatas as $key => $formattedData) {    
    foreach ($formattedData as $keyFormat => $valueFormat) {        
        $brandDataArray['sales_price']  += $valueFormat['total_price'];
    }           
}
```